# Finding instances of parameters in function in directory of php files

Tags: php

I have a directory with a number of php files, there is a function getOpt() that’s used in most of the files, with different parameters. For example:

```
getOpt(sometext)
```

or

```
getOpt(sometext, someothertext)
```

or

```
getOpt(sometext2)
```

I'm trying to get anything that's in the parenthesis and figure out which files it pops up in and if possible how many times.

For example the output I'm trying achieve would look something like this:

"sometext" is used in x.php (2 times), y.php (1 times), z.php (4 times)

"sometext2" is used in y.php(1 times), z.php (3 times)

etc...

Is this something that can be done with a lengthy grep command?

I've tried:

```
grep -o -a -m 1 -h -r “getOpt(*” . | head -1 > ouput.txt
```

But I'm not sure how to capture until the close parenthesis, instead of the first instance of the function name. How else could I go about this?

Comment: Might I ask what the purpose of this is? It seems like an ... odd ... task.  There may be a better way to achieve your ultimate goal.

Comment: The function is used to toggle features on a website. The "sometext" corresponds to a feature. I'm trying to collect all the features that can be enabled currently so that they can be documented.